# how to replace a string in javascript after the specific index

Tags: javascript

Hi I am having the string which contains html content and I want use javascript to replace the tag <p class="MsoNormal"> with '' empty space and i want to replace corresponding closing tag </p> with <br> tag in that string.

If I use

first line:

```
str=str.replace(/<p class=\"MsoNormal\">/g,'');
```

second line:                                                                    `str=str.replace(/<\/p>/g,'<br>');`

All the closing </p> tag get remove .But i want to replace the closing </p> tag which has the opening tag of "<p class="MsoNormal">".

The first line of script is okay of me .What should i use to replace that corresponding closing tag in the second line.

Comment: `str=str.replace(/<p class=\"MsoNormal\">([\w\W]+?)<\/p>/g,'$1<br>');`

Comment: Note that this solution is not general, as it does not support nesting. Luckily, paragraphs shouldn't be nested. But doing this with real DOM is much more universal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: Output is what I got from your question is to replace with **Empty String**

```
var replaceTag = function(str, replaceTagString, endTagString) {
    var str = '';
    while(str.indexOf(replaceTagString) != -1) {
        //search for </p> after my matched String
        var indexOfClosingTag = str.indexOf(endTagString, str.indexOf(replaceTagString))
        //Replace </p> using Substring
        str = str.substr(0,indexOfClosingTag) + "<br>" + str.substr(indexOfClosingTag + endTagString.length,k.length)
        //Replace your main String
        str = str.replace(replaceTagString,'')
    }
    return str
}

var k = "<p class='MsoNormal'>something</p><p>other p tag</p><h1>I am h1</h1><p>Hello p</p><p class='MsoNormal'>Replace My Tag too</p>"

replaceTag(k, "<p class='MsoNormal'>", "</p>")
```

Output:

```
"something<p>other p tag</p><h1>I am h1</h1><p>Hello p</p>Replace My Tag too"
```

Concept:

> string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)
>
> Start searching for **End of the Tag (P)** after my current matched string position

Comment: Thanks @Harpreet Singh it help me a lot ...And i also want to replace the corresponding closing </p> with <br>.How to do so.

Comment: Thanks   @Harpreet Singh                                                                             I am getting error at line          "var indexOfClosingTag = str.indexOf(endTagString, str.indexOf(replaceTagString))"    -->                A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.        And i stop the scripts.

Comment: @goku, I think you have given some wrong input and the while loop is becoming infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Define a function yourself like this-->

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
        return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
str = str.replaceAt(3, "</p>");
```